# Yii Booster Gridview table joining table

Tags: php, yii

i want to create a table like this [Yii Booster Gridview table](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/widgets/grids/view/gridview.html)

here is my code in controller:

```
$rawData=Jobspecs::model()->with('customer')->findAll();
$gridDataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($rawData, array(
    'id'=>'user',

    'sort'=>array(
        'attributes'=>array(
             'id', 'customer',
            ),

        ),

    ));
$gridColumns = array(

    array('name'=>'id', 'header'=>'Js No.', 'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 60px')),

    array('name'=>'WHAT TO PUT HERE TO SHOW CUSTOMER NAME', 'header'=>'Customer Name'),

    array(

        'htmlOptions' => array('nowrap'=>'nowrap'),

        'class'=>'booster.widgets.TbButtonColumn',

        'viewButtonUrl'=>null,

    )

    );
```

in my model sapcustomers:

```
return array(
            'customer'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Sapcustomers', 'customer'),
        );
```

jobspecs model

```
return array(
            'cardname'=>array( self::HAS_MANY, 'Jobspecs', 'customer' ),
        );
```

my view

```
<?php
        $this->widget(
            'booster.widgets.TbGridView',
            array(
                'type' => 'bordered',
                'dataProvider' => $gridDataProvider,
                'template' => "{items}",
                'columns' => $gridColumns,
            )
        );
?>
```

as you can see i joined sapcustomers and jobspecs table. my question is what code i need to put on the `$gridcolums` to show the customer name data from the table sapcustomer. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
$gridColumns = array(
    [...]

    array(
         'name'=>'customer', 
         'value'=>'$data->customer->name',
         'header'=>'Customer Name'
    ),
);
```

**Explanation**

The `$data` stands for the `Jobspecs-model` from the actual row. Then you access the related `customer` and his `name`.

Comment: how can i write this? i wite it like this `array('name'=>array('name'=>'customer', 'value'=>'$data->customer->name'), 'header'=>'Customer Name'),`
but it returns:

`Error 500
call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object`

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object :(

Comment: @are you sure that the relation is called `customer`? try `cardname` instead. (`'$data->cardname->name',`) This (in my answer `customer`) needs to be the relation name.

Comment: my table field is `Sapcustomers.cardname`, this is what i put in my model
`Sapcustomers.id=Jobspecs.customer`
 `return array(
            'customer'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Sapcustomers', 'customer'),
        );`

Comment: @thisisME did you tested this relation?